# How to get "any" mongodb result key from object

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a PHP script that returns a CSV formatted result:

```
# cat query.php
<?php

include '../misc.php';
$values=$_GET?$_GET:$_POST;

{
  $ts = isset($values['t'])?strtotime($values['t']):strtotime("-1 hour");
  $result=Query('iot.data',['key' => $values['key'], 'timestamp' => array('$gte' => $ts)],['projection' => array('_id' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1, $values['col'] => 1), 'sort' => array('timestamp' => 1)]);

    if ($values['col'] == 'temp1') echo "Timestamp, Temperature\n";
    if ($values['col'] == 'BusV2') echo "Timestamp, Battery V\n";
    if ($values['col'] == 'uv1') echo "Timestamp, UV\n";


  foreach ($result as $r) { 
    $d = date('c',$r->timestamp);
    if (isset($r->temp1)) echo "$d, $r->temp1\n";
    if (isset($r->BusV2)) echo "$d, $r->BusV2\n";
    if (isset($r->uv1)) echo "$d, $r->uv1\n";
  };
};
```

With the "col" parameter I can decide what key is returned with a timestamp.

How can I get the desired result without those IF's inside the foreach loop?

How would I code something like:

```
foreach ($result as $r) { 
    $d = date('c',$r->timestamp); 
    echo "$d, $r->$values['col']\n" // where object $r key comes from variable 'col'
}
```

It doesn't help if I change that foreach to:
`foreach ($result as $r => $v) {`

because that `$v` doesn't get value of key `$r`, `$v` is now what `$r` was before...

Result of `print_r($v);`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [temp1] => 25.2
    [timestamp] => 1470304854
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve, you would use:

```
foreach ($result as $r) { 
    $d = date('c',$r->timestamp);    
    echo "$d, " . $r->{$values['col']} . "\n";
};
```

It seems that your mongo is returning a `stdClass Object` which you can access using `->`, which is why `$r[$values['col']]` was giving a 500 error.

Comment: Don't work! When php hits '$r[$values['col']]' it returns (to http server) error 500. When php try to interpreter '$r->$values['col']' it don't give error, but just stop doing.. None of lines is executed after that point. Structure what mongo-driver returns is something special.. I think.

Comment: what does `print_r($r)` return when you put it before `$d = date('c',$r->timestamp);` in your foreach?

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [humidity1] => 68.9
    [timestamp] => 1470391190
)
2016-08-05T12:59:50+03:00, 68.9

Comment: @JJussi, see edit, try that, if that doesn't work, then I am unsure how to help you further

Comment: That helped.. Thank you!

Comment: @JJussi, no problem, enjoy